# Queue list output is not coming out like it should

Tags: javascript, queue

The output that i should be getting looks like this:

with an input of 10

Iteration 0:  L1 = 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, Q1 = ,

Iteration 1:  L1 = 3 5 7 9, Q1 = 2

Iteration 2: L1 = 5 7, Q1 = 2 3

Iteration 3: L1 = 7, Q1 = 2 3 5

Iteration 4: L1 = , Q1 = 2 3 5 7

But, I keep getting this output:

Iteration 0: L1 = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, Q1 =

Iteration 4: L1 = Q1 =2,3,5,7,

Iterations 1-3 will not output...

```js
function Queue() {

var items = [];
var front=0;
var rear=0;
var size=20;

this.insert = function(element){
if(rear==size)
alert("Queue is full!");
else
{
items[rear]=element;
rear++;
}
};

this.delete = function(){
var deletedElement;
if(front==rear)
alert("Queue is empty!");
else
{
deletedElement=items[front];
front++;
}

return deletedElement;
};

this.deleteByElement = function(element) {
var index = items.indexOf(element);
if (index > -1) {
   items.splice(index, 1);
rear--;
}else {
alert("element not found ");
}
}

this.deleteByFactor = function(element) {
var isdeleted=false;
for(var i=front;i<rear;i++)
{
if(items[i]%element==0)
{
this.deleteByElement(items[i]);
        isdeleted=true;
}
}
        return isdeleted;
}

this.isEmpty = function(){
return rear == 0;
};

this.size = function(){
return items.length;
};

this.clear = function(){
items = [];
};

this.print = function(){
var queue='';
for(var i=front;i<rear;i++)
{
queue = queue + items[i]+",";
}
return queue;
};
}

function createNewQueue(queue)
{
var newqueue = new Queue();
var iter=0;
var start=2;
  
//Initial iteration
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Iteration "+ iter + ": L1 = " + queue.print() + " Q1 =" + newqueue.print();

while(!queue.isEmpty())
{
if(queue.deleteByFactor(start))
{
iter++;
newqueue.insert(start);

document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "Iteration " + iter + ": L1 = " + queue.print() + " Q1 =" + newqueue.print();
  
}
start++;
  
}   
  
}
var element = prompt("Enter Queue Element", "");
var queue = new Queue();
for(var i=2;i<=element;i++)
queue.insert(i);
//calling create new queue method
createNewQueue(queue);
```

```html
<p>Queue Program</p>

<p id="output1"></p>
<p id="output2"></p>
```

Comment: Looks like you're not incrementing `iter` each time, and you are overwriting the contents of `#output2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, looks like there's just a couple things.

First, check your counter variable.  You want to update `iter` with every iteration of the loop, not just just inside the `if` statement.

Secondly, your output to the div `#output2` every iteration overwrites the existing output.  You'd want to append the new text.

Something like this would work:

**Updated Code**

```
function createNewQueue(queue) {
  var newqueue = new Queue();
  var iter=0;
  var start=2;

  //Initial iteration
  var output = document.getElementById("output1");  //use a variable to store the output element
output.innerHTML = "<p>Iteration "+ iter + ": L1 = " + queue.print() + " Q1 =" + newqueue.print() + "</p>";

  while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    iter++; //make sure to increment the counter with each loop

    if(queue.deleteByFactor(start)) {           
      newqueue.insert(start);

      //append the new output to the existing output  
      output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + "<p>Iteration " + iter + ": L1 = " + queue.print() + " Q1 =" + newqueue.print() + "</p>";
    }
    start++;
  } //while    
} //createNewQueue()
```

**Output**

> Iteration 0: L1 = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, Q1 =
>   Iteration 1: L1 = 3,5,7,9, Q1 =2,
>   Iteration 2: L1 = 5,7, Q1 =2,3,
>   Iteration 4: L1 = 7, Q1 =2,3,5,
>   Iteration 6: L1 = Q1 =2,3,5,7,

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/abnbpp01/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Helps a lot thanks, but can i ask you why your iteration #s go 0,1,2,4,6....They should be 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  In your code, the if statement `if(queue.deleteByFactor(start))` is never entered during iterations 3 and 5, because your `deleteByFactor()` function returns false during those iterations.